# Is there a way to only detect keydown event on a readyonly codemirror editor

Tags: javascript, typescript, codemirror

I have a requirement where I have to detect a keydown event on CodeMirror editor, but the editor is in readonly mode, I don't want to change anything on the editor, Only the event should be fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```js
let someInput = document.getElementById("someInput");


someInput.addEventListener("keypress",  function(e){ console.log(`key = ${e.key} code=${e.keyCode}`)})
```

```html
<input id="someInput" type="text" readonly>
```

Comment: Yes, I need something like this, but on Codemirror editor and also is it possible to get the keyCode of function keys?